# react kids app positioning buttons

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, react-native

**Need to position black widow to to center left and hulk to left bottom but cant figure it out anyone have any tips plus i only want to isolate the button to the picture  not to sure if i need to separate the buttons and position individually..

Here is the code from the React native project..**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,ImageBackground,button,  
TouchableOpacity, Dimensions,Button} from 'react-native';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width; 
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const getPosition = (left, top, width, height) => ({ 
  left: width * left, 
  top: height * top 
})



export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
   return (
     <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
 <ImageBackground source={{uri: 'https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/usa_avengers_sb_bkgd8_1024_0ae5b001.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1024%2C576'}}
    style={{width: width, height: height,flexDirection:'colum'}}> 



    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.spiderman}>
      <Image source={{uri: 'http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Spider-Man-Transparent-Background.png'}}
   style={{width: 200, height:300,}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.hulk}>
      <Image source={{uri:
'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/avengers-assemble/images/d/d6/Usa_avengers_skchi_blackwidow_n_6e8100ad.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/449?cb=20170426073401'}}
   style={{width: 150, height: 80, position:'top',}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.blkwidow}>
      <Image source={{uri: 'https://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1516942387Hulk-Png-Cartoon.png'}}
   style={{width: 200, height: 250,position:'top'}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </ImageBackground>
  </View>
  );
 }
}
///need help with coloring each icon
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: 'blue',
position:'right',
alignItems: 'flex-end',
justifyContent: 'space-between',
width: 50,
height: 50,
bottom: 50,
left: Dimensions.get('window').width -70,
zIndex: 10,
  },
  spiderman: {
borderRadius: 2,
padding: -100,
marginBottom: 2,
shadowColor: 'white',
shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 0 },
shadowRadius: 0,
shadowOpacity: 0.45,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set your container style as the value fo any component's style property. Looking at spiderman, your touchable container is only 50x50 so it won't wrap your whole image (200x300). get rid of all properties on your spiderman style except border radius and you should be good. add an onPress prop `onPress={this.helloWorld}` to your touchable to make it do something.

Comment: how so i set a postion for each character i want spiderman top left black widow center right and hulk bottom left thank in advance

Comment: ultimately i want to add videos to the characters when they are pressed but i gotta get the positions right first

Comment: I don't have time to write an example here, but I'll just say that I highly  recommend using flexbox for positioning just about everything, and this site www.flexboxfroggy.com is a great place to learn about positioning things.